# In Python, why can't an accumulator generators be written with lambdas?

Tags: python, functional-programming

Paul Graham [describes](http://www.paulgraham.com/icad.html) the following problem:

> We want to write a function that generates accumulators-- a function that takes a number n, and returns a function that takes another number i and returns n incremented by i.

He says that whereas such a function could be implemented in Lisp/Ruby/Perl as simply as something like

```
(defun foo (n)
  (lambda (i) (incf n i)))
```

, in Python it would be written

```
class foo:
  def __init__(self, n):
      self.n = n
  def __call__(self, i):
      self.n += i
      return self.n
```

So my question is, What exactly about Python (apart from the lack of support for multi-line lambdas) prevents you from implementing an accumulator generator in the terse style of the first code sample above? Would Python ever support such a thing in the future, as Paul Graham speculates?

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been closed. The last sentence is probably too inclined toward speculative responses and arguments about the relative merits of such a feature, but other than that, this is a great question.

Comment: For those with sufficient karma, **consider nominating this question for reopening** (e.g., by clicking the above `reopen` link). As [Kyle Strand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1858225/kyle-strand) suggests, this question is indeed appropriate for StackOverflow's formatting and was improperly closed on spurious grounds.

Answer (score 3):

The example if first of all contrived. After defining the accumulator, you would in Python use it like this:

```
acc = foo(6)
acc(2)
acc(4)
```

For what use? In Python you would do this:

```
acc = 6
acc += 2
acc += 4
```

I don't know if defining an accumulator in lisp makes sense, but in Python you don't need to define one, because you would have it built in, so to speak.

Second of all the question you ask hits the nail on the head. What prevents Python from doing this in a "terse" style? Because the attitude of Python is that it will going to be a language that is quick to develop in and that is maintainable, and that means easy to read. Code golf and obtuse, terse code is not a part of what Python is designed for.

But ultimately, the reason Python will never evolve this functionality is that is relies on integers being mutable, ie that you can do something like:

```
>>> g = 6
>>> g++
>>> g
7
```

This will not happen in Python, where integers are immutable. You can't increase the value of an integer. This simplifies both the language and it's use a lot. For example, if integers were mutable, they could not be used as keys in dictionaries.

Essentially the example centers around increasing the value of integers, something you can't do in Python. In Python, when you add two integers you get a third integer back. You do not increase the value of the first one.

So Python will never become lisp, and only people who have used lisp for too long thinks it should, or persist in the "python is almost lisp" idiom. And it can't do an accumulator in just a few lines, because it neither needs to nor wants to.

Comment: It's not "the int object" that's an accumulator in Python, but rather "a variable".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Well, the world "variable" is problematic in python, but yeah.

Comment: What exactly do you mean that you cannot do something like `g++`? How is that semantically different from `g += 1`?

Comment: @Jian: g++ increases g. You can't do that in Python. g += 1 is the same as g = g + 1, which reassigns g to a new value.

Comment: Heh, force of habit. Good to see that some "big names" agree that the term is problematic for Python though :)

Comment: Blaming this on Python integers being immutable makes absolutely no sense. Common Lisp integers are immutable as well.  The (incf ...) in the lisp example is a macro that does exactly the same thing as += in Python, except that it is more flexible because it is an expression, not a statement

Answer (score 2):

He actually describes one reason in [his followup post](http://www.paulgraham.com/icadmore.html).  His brief discussion there covers both of the reasons I mention below, although his take on it is a bit different.

As he talks about earlier in the post, part of what he's concerned with is the difference between statements and expressions.  In Python `+=` is a statement, and lambdas cannot contain statements, only expressions.

However, there's another issue.  He wants his function to take "a number" as input, but he makes a distinction between "plus" and "increment" (as do many programming languages).  However, my own position would be that there is no such distinction for *numbers*, only for *variables* (or "objects" or similar things).  There is no such thing as "incrementing" the number 5.  In this sense, you still can't write a Python lambda that increments a variable containing a builtin in numeric type, but you can do it if it accepts a mutable object instead of a raw number.  And you could write your own MutableNumber class that works this way and make it totally interoperable with existing numeric types.  So in this sense the reason Python doesn't support has to do with the design of its types (i.e., numbers are immutable) rather than the sort of functional issues he discusses in the post.

Whether any of this is actually a problem for the language is, of course, another question.

Comment: No. It has nothing to do with numbers being immutable, as long as variables can be assigned a new integer. Lisp integers are also immutable. The incf form in his example is a macro, not a function call.

Answer (score 2):

It can. The trick is to use a container to hold the original integer and to set and access this number without using the assignment operator.

```
>>> g=lambda n: (lambda d: lambda i: (d.__setitem__('v', d['v']+i),d['v'])[1])({'v': n})
>>> x=g(3)
>>> x(1)
4
>>> x(1)
5
>>> x(10)
15
>>>
```

Comment: Yeah, but can you really call that "terse"? it's almost as many characters as the class example. :-)

Comment: It's definitely not tarse but was a good golfing exercise :). Another approach will be to replace the second lambda with a default dictionary parameter:`g=lambda n,d={}:lambda i:(d.__setitem__(0,d.get(0,n)+i),d[0])[1]`

Answer (score 0):

trying to do this as clear as I could, separating lambdas to variables:

```
concat = lambda arr, val: (arr.append(val), arr)[1]
f = lambda n: (lambda i: concat(n,n.pop(0)+i)[0])
accumulate = lambda n: f([n])
a=accumulate(9)
a(1) #10
a(2) #12
```